# How to give input to my trained machine learning model to predict the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I have trained a machine learning model to predict the price of tomato using the last 5 year data. Now I want to give some information as input to get predicted output but I don't know how to do it. These are the feature which I used to train the model District Name, Market Name, Variety, Grade, Modal_Price_(Rs./Quintal)_log, year, month and day.

```
#XGBoost
xgbm = XGBRegressor()
xgbm.fit(x_train,y_train)
preds = xgbm.predict(x_test)

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, preds))
print("RMSE: %f" % (rmse))
```

RMSE: 0.285714

Answer (score -1):

If you have read a csv file for all you is to make sure that the file with the same name is present in the same directory. If you are using pandas to create dataframe then.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

if you want to give raw input refer the official [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/input_format.html)

Comment: I have trained my model using the data now i want to give some raw data as input so that my trained model will give me predicted price of tomato

Comment: let me get back to you